# Appearance of Sturm-Liouville Problem in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-equations, eigenvalue

I am considering the below ODE (ordinary differential equation), which can be studied using techniques from [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).

The context is mathematical, but I was wondering if anyone recognises where this equation might appear naturally in physics (or one similar to it)? I was thinking perhaps for eigenvalue problems in non-relativistic quantum mechanics:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg( \frac{1}{(1+ x^2)^2} \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg) + \lambda x^2 y =0 \ .$$

Comment: You can try rewriting this equation as $-\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2} - V_1(x) i \frac{d \psi(x)}{d x} + V_2(x) \psi(x) = \lambda \psi(x) $. The interpretation would then be that $\psi(x)$ is the wave function of energy $\lambda$ representing a particle living in a classically quantized potential V = $V_1(x) p + V_2(x)$ where $p = m v$ is the particle's momentum. In order to write an equation in this form, you can multiply the equation by some function of $x$, do a change of coordinates, and redefine the wave function $\psi(x) = f(x) y(x)$, where $f(x)$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @AdrienMartina I see how this works formally but what is the physical motivation and/or example of an application?